# What is the difference between SplObjectStorage::contains and SplObjectStorage::offsetExists?

Tags: php, spl, php-internals, splobjectstorage

The PHP documentation is not very explicit and only states that:

**SplObjectStorage::offsetExists** *Checks whether an object exists in the storage.* (PHP >= 5.3.0)

**SplObjectStorage::contains** *Checks if the storage contains the object provided.* (PHP >= 5.1.0)

Which pretty much seems the same thing to me.

**QUESTION:** Apart from offsetExists being only available in 5.3.0, what is the difference between the 2?

---

small test I conducted...

```
$s = new SplObjectStorage();
$o1 = new StdClass();
$o2 = new StdClass();
$o3 = "I'm not an object!";
$s->attach($o1);

var_dump($s->contains($o1));
var_dump($s->offsetExists($o1));
echo '<br>';
var_dump($s->contains($o2));
var_dump($s->offsetExists($o2));
echo '<br>';
var_dump($s->contains($o3));
var_dump($s->offsetExists($o3));
```

output:

```
boolean true
boolean true

boolean false
boolean false

Warning: SplObjectStorage::contains() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in index.php on line 15
null

Warning: SplObjectStorage::offsetExists() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in index.php on line 16
null
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are both exactly the same.

`offsetExists` is defined as a **method alias** of `contains` and is included simply for compliance with the `ArrayAccess` interface.

You can [see for yourself in the source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.4.5/ext/spl/spl_observer.c#L987) that `SPL_MA` (method alias) is being used, and also that there are a couple of other aliases set up.

- offsetExists = contains
- offsetSet = attach
- offsetUnset = detach